Runtime reflection is not supported for public javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.getStatusInfo()
I am using Quarkus 2.15.3.Final and Java 17 (Running Quarkus native-image plugin on GraalVM 22.3.3 Java 17 CE) and when testing several endpoints I get the error detailed.
com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Runtime reflection is not supported for public javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.AbstractBuiltResponse.getStatusInfo()\n\tat org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:89)\n\tat java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.acquireMethodAccessor(Method.java:76)\n\tat java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4624)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3869)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.microservice.OriginacionMicroService.executeSelect(OriginacionMicroService.java:127)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.microservice.OriginacionMicroService_ClientProxy.executeSelect(Unknown Source)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.service.InfoAdicionalDocumentoService.obtenerInfoAdicionalDocumento(InfoAdicionalDocumentoService.java:65)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.service.InfoAdicionalDocumentoService.getInfoAdicionalDocumento(InfoAdicionalDocumentoService.java:54)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.service.InfoAdicionalDocumentoService_ClientProxy.getInfoAdicionalDocumento(Unknown Source)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.controller.InfoAdicionalDocumentoController.obtenerInfoAdicionalDocumento(InfoAdicionalDocumentoController.java:80)\n\tat ar.com.hipotecario.originacion.controller.InfoAdicionalDocumentoController_ClientProxy.obtenerInfoAdicionalDocumento(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat
`<properties>
<compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
<quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
<quarkus.platform.version>2.15.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
<skipITs>true</skipITs>
<surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>`


Have you tried with more recent versions of Quarkus?

@geoand Unfortunately I can't upgrade the quarkus version, but I was able to solve it by adding some entries to the reflect-config.json. Thank you so much!

New entries to reflect-config.json =
{
"name": "javax.ws.rs.core.Response",
"allDeclaredFields": true,
"queryAllDeclaredMethods": true,
"methods": [
{
"name": "getHeaders",
"parameterTypes": [
    ]
  }
]

},
{
"name": "javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status",
"allDeclaredFields": true,
"queryAllDeclaredMethods": true
},
{
"name": "javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType",
"queryAllDeclaredMethods": true
}


I'm curious to know why you can't upgrade

The devops team does not have the pipeline prepared with a more recent version, so we have to work with this one :D

That's unfortunate :(
